# Use phpBB credentials for a blog

Tags: wordpress, credentials, phpbb

Is there any way to setup a Wordpress blog (or any other blog system) and let users use the same credentials used in a phpBB forum...a sort of database sharing.

Answer (score 0):

there's no out-of-the-box method of sharing PHPBB users with WordPress - it would involve modifying WordPress quite a bit to implement it...

there is a blogging site conversion for phpbb, which converts phpbb into a blog.. and I guess you could probably hack it a bit so that you could run forums and a blog from the same database?

http://www.outshine.com/software/phpbb-blog/index.php